# ngaudio screen's click stops the audio

Tags: angularjs, audio

In AngularJs 1, when using the ngAudio service, and playing audio like this :

```
$scope.audio = ngAudio.load("abc.wav");
$scope.audio.play();
```

After the sound is played, a click on the screen stops it. 
Why is that, and how can I change it ?

I'll appreciate your answers. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try running `ngAudio.setUnlock( false );` on the ngAudio service.

The culprit is on line 147 of `angular.audio.js`.